# Can we use Site.com templates/pages in Community builder?

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, community-builder

I have created a Site page in Site.com studio and then converted into a site template. Now my questions is will I be able to use this template in Community builder?

Comment: if the below post answered your question, consider accepting it so it may help others. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No,

The lightning community builder uses a template structure of its own, if you were to change it you would lose all functionality of the community builder.

This is why you are able to create new pages from templates by selecting pages, New Page :

[image]

select a page type:

[image]

select a template:

[image]

and then you can customize the page with [custom theme layouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm) + Css in the [community branding](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_designer_brand.htm&language=en_US&type=0).